# AsyncTask executes but only sometimes

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

So i use this code to call my AsyncTask

```
Log.d("before","make_connection");
new Make_Connection().execute();
Log.d("after","make_connection");
```

My class

```
private class Make_Connection extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{

    final int port = 4445;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Toast.makeText(KeyboardActivity.this,"This runs",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.d("Connection","Started");
        Log.e("Connec","this runs");
        try {
            socket = new Socket(IP,port);
            //dout = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            //dout.writeUTF("Connection Formed");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(KeyboardActivity.this,"Connection Made",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
```

Now i can see in the android monitor that these two are always execute

```
Log.d("before","make_connection");
Log.d("after","make_connection");
```

But half of the time i cannot see the output produced by

```
Log.d("Connection","Started");
Log.e("Connec","this runs");
```

Even though `onPreExecute()` runs properly everytime.
I have tested on two diffent mobilies running 7.1 and 7.0

Can someone please tell me why this is happening

Comment: How many async task do you have in this application?

Comment: 3 one runs in parallel with this one and the other executes before this one

Comment: that's the problem. You've to tell them to run parallel

Comment: i am new to android so can you direct me to some documentation as to how i do that

Comment: see the answer..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
new Make_Connection().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

instead of only

```
new Make_Connection().execute();
```

This is needed, because in Android SDK 13 or higher they run serially by default. So if you want to run more than one `AsyncTask` simultaneously, use `executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)` 
For more details, see explanation under **order of execution** from [This docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTasks are run sequentially by default. They all execute on the same executor. Taken from here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke
>   executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with
>   THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

Comment: so one activity can not run two asynctask at the same time?

Comment: It can, with executeOnExecutor().