# Nested / normal for loops in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I've been testing some asynctasks in android.

But I found some illogical outcomes on these codes:

```
int a1Sum = 0;
int a2Sum = 0;

long a1Time = 0;
long a2Time = 0;

private class Async1 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        a1Time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            publishProgress();
        }
        return "You are at PostExecute";
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... arg0) {
        a1Sum++;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d("A1 Time", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() - a1Time)); // records the executing time
        AsyncTask async2 = new Async2().execute();
    }
}

private class Async2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        a2Time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
                    for (int l = 0; l < 10; l++) {
                        publishProgress();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return "You are at PostExecute";
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... arg0) {
        a2Sum++;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d("A2 Time", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() - a2Time)); // records the executing time
    }
}
```

those two asynctasks do the same jobs but here is the illogical part:

as you see on the code, `a1Time` and `a2Time` records the executing time and here is the result of them:

```
D/A1 Time: 1025
D/A2 Time: 768
D/A1 Time: 1022
D/A2 Time: 716
D/A1 Time: 1017
D/A2 Time: 729
D/A1 Time: 1063
D/A2 Time: 830
D/A1 Time: 1059
D/A2 Time: 784
```

My question is: What makes the `Async2` run faster?

Comment: @Kaushal28 But shouldn't the `Async1` faster because its simpler?

Comment: Interesting. Now turn around. Let thread 1 be started by thread 2.

Comment: If the ```doInBackground()``` implementation of ```Async2``` is exactly the same as ```Aynsc1```, will it end up with the same result or will they have same execution time? Also it'll be better to dissect the execution time more as the code is switching between main UI thread and background thread which adds an overhead, hence track the time the ```doInBackground()``` implementations take. I think that they'll end up with close execution times. And lastly, (I'm probably asking for too much, apologies) will it be same if ```executeOnExecutor(THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)``` instead of ```execute()```?

Comment: @greenapps ooooooh! The results are: 
`D/A2 Time: 649

D/A1 Time: 656`

Comment: @ahasbini That's also a good point, using the `executeOnExecutor(THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)` gave me the result of `D/A1 Time: 666
D/A2 Time: 668`. The results were different!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a recap of the found results in the comments, the test results were as follows (Note that the AsyncTasks are executed sequentially​ and not in parallel):

Executing `Async1` by `Async2` resulted with same execution times. This can only be reasoned with OS optimization of the executions however the test could result differently in other cases such as different devices or even in different times of executing the test.

Executing the tasks using `executeOnExecutor(THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)` instead of `execute()` resulted with the same execution times. This could be reasoned with the idea of the OS immediately starting the background thread hence since both compute the same number of loops with minor differences in execution they'll end up with the similar execution time.

Further dissection is still needed which is timing only the `doInBackground()` implementations in order to count out the overhead of switching between the main UI thread and the background thread.

Comment: Appearing quite Acceptable, plus one for that

Answer (score 1):

Your 2<sup>nd</sup> thread is not slow but your both threads are running in serial order. For Asynctasks, If both threads are started simultaneously then they will run in serial order by default. As mentioned in comments `AnsncTask.executeOnExector(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)` will force two asyncTasks to run parallel. Refer this for more on order of execution:  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43426810/asynctask-executes-but-only-sometimes/43426869#43426869)

And when they run parallel, they will show the same counts. The difference in your results are because of complexity of executed functions in each threads.

Comment: Thanks for wrapping it up, but why executing `Async1` by `Async2` gives the same execution time?

Comment: Its 649 and 656 (by @greenapps)

Comment: His code shows calling the tasks in sequential order and they are not executed in parallel. ```Async2``` is executed within the ```onPostExecute``` of ```Async1```. However the ```executeOnExecutor(THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)``` will cause the difference in the result as the OS will start the thread immediately instead of waiting for other ```AsyncTasks``` to finish completely.

Comment: @BedrockDev yeah that's quite a mystery how ```Async1``` by ```Async2``` gave the same execution time. I believe it's OS related on how it optimized the execution and hence not something to be relied on.